# Using firestore for spring-boot rest api

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make my own rest-api using spring-boot. Should I jump into using firestore as my primary database ? I have searched over internet but found nothing essential for using sping-boot with firestore database. I don't know the issues of using normal database or firestore with spring boot.

Answer (score -1):

You can use firestore as your database, implementation is pretty forward
[enter link description here](https://javabelazy.blogspot.com/)

use the following dependency

dependencies {
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-firestore'
}

Autowire your firestore instance

@Autowired
Firestore firestore;

For writing to firestore use the following code

WriteResult writeResult = this.firestore.document("users/joe").set(data).get();

you have to specify your project id in application properties
spring.cloud.gcp.firestore.project-id = abcdefg