# Too Much Overhead with Firestore and Spring Boot JPA repository

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on my own personal project of a JIRA-like ticket tracker that I can use for my own projects. I've decided to use the GCP stack and have a Vue.js frontend hosted on firebase and a Spring Boot App Engine backend.

I was originally thinking of having a firestore with the project, and this is where I will keep track of the tickets. I was then going through the firestore on the App Engine start and setting up a JPA repository with all tickets currently in there. Any creation or modification of tickets will go from the frontend UI -> spring boot repo -> update the firestore. I have created an Entity/Class called Ticket which is what I am using to store all the data for each document from firestore and is what is being kept in the repo, and plan to make REST API calls to the backend in order to create new tickets/modify current ones.

My question is as I was building out this last section it seems actually like having this spring boot repo may be too much overhead and data being passed around, slowing down the application (or even just pure duplicate code). Is it better to just use pure Firestore and modify the data directly there, or am I on the right track and actually this Spring Boot repo should be kept in?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55018663/using-firestore-for-spring-boot-rest-api

Comment: @Konzern I already know how to connect spring boot and firestore, have it working already. My question was whether it was better to just essentially have javascript calls to modify the firestore database, or go through a spring boot backend to handle it all

Comment: better handle it using spring boot backend